# Kubuntu 14.04: i686 version to run on Win8 64bit laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit, kubuntu, uefi, 14.04

Am existing Kubuntu user.

I am about to install Kubuntu 14.04 on a new(ish) Dell Inspirion 17 7000.
Its currently running Windows 8.0 64bit, so I presume its in UEFI mode.
I'd like to keep Win8 on it in case I ever need to run an odd program that needs Windows.

Looking at the Ubuntu Wiki: it tells me that I **need** to install a 64bit version of Ubuntu, Kubuntu in my case. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

I look at the Kubuntu flavours available on the Download site it only gives me the i386 & AMD64 versions (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/trusty/release/).  Ubuntu does have a i686 version available.

So I am a little stuck. Any suggestions please?

Cheers, thanks

Andy

Comment: Read the descriptions: "Desktop image for 64-bit PC (AMD64) computers (standard download)". amd does not mean the company but the architecture. All 64-bits are named amd64.

Comment: This is the initial first Kubuntu installation on the Dell laptop. The existing, older installation is on a HP laptop to be superceded by the new Dell one.

Comment: Thanks All.  Have downloaded the 64bit DVD now fine.  
Can someone confirm whether I can do a plain Jane install from the DVD itself with Trusty, or do I still have to make the various UEFI/Win8 mods described in the Ubuntu UEFI wiki (i.e. are these mods for older versions of [x]ubuntu)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have Kubuntu installed on the laptop you want to upgrade? Or do you have Kubuntu on a different machine and would like to put another copy on your laptop?

Do not install Kubuntu I686 on a 64bit machine. It will only allow you to use 4gig of ram. I'm going to guess you have more than that.

The AMD64 part probably threw you off. They really should call it x64 as it applies to AMD and Intel based machines.

As far as keeping Windows 8. You will have the option during Kubuntu setup to "INSTALL ALONGSIDE WINDOWS 8. I think it's the first option. I believe the screen after that, you have a slider bar that will let you resize your partition.

Comment: The term "AMD64" is used because AMD invented the current 64-bit variant of the x86 architecture. Another name for the latter is "IA32," for "Intel Architecture 32." That name is used even in reference to 32-bit AMD CPUs, so the situation with AMD64 naming is the same thing, just with the players reversed.